# can not create core in solr [ERROR: Solr requires authentication]

Tags: solr, ubuntu-16.04

when I create solr core:

```
bin/solr create -c my_core
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Solr requires authentication for http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system. Please supply valid credentials. HTTP code=401
```

even I had logged in into solr admin panel. is there any way to provide my credential info with the `create` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if it is an old question.
Just for reference in case somebody like me looks for the answer in the future.

In my case of Solr 6 setting the following two environment variables did the job:

```
export SOLR_AUTH_TYPE='basic'
export SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS='-Dbasicauth=username:password'
```

Now I was able to issue 'bin/solr create ...' etc. from the same console session

Comment: Nowadays, in 7.7, you're supposed to run `solr auth enable` with a bunch of arguments (run `--help` first).  The `-prompt` argument straight up doesn't work, says it can't find the solrIncludeFile argument even if you supply it.  The second variable will end up looking like `SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dsolr.httpclient.config=/opt/solr/server/solr/basicAuth.conf"`.

Answer (score 0):

as work around not a solution, I had to delete the security,json file, restart solr, then create the core finally put back the security.json file.

Answer (score 0):

in my case in solr 6.5 I did these steps:
1: disable security option in solr, at the end of lines should be `sudo nano /opt/solr/server/etc/webdefault.xml`

```
<!-- <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config> -->
```

**aftter restart solr**

```
sudo service solr restart
```